# How should I configure partitions and volumes on raid10 DAS for Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, storage

I am looking to configure a single server with Hyper-V running on DAS for high intensity workloads. I have 4 x 1.2TB SSDs that I have configured in RAID10 using the hardware RAID config tool. I have installed Windows Server 2016 Core and used Windows Setup to create a partition(s) for the local OS (50GB).

I have installed the Hyper-V server role but am confused as to how I should manage the storage from here. I am not a storage boff (I guess that's fairly evident) and have read different things that have left me even more confused.

I would like to know how I should create partitions and volumes using diskpart (primary, extended, logical? one volume, lots of smaller volumes? ) and then how I configure Hyper-V effectively - do I create each volume with a drive letter and then distribute the VMs across them evenly or save them all to a single 'D drive' volume on the HV host?

Comment: Considering the hardware you've got to work with, don't complicate this. Create a single Windows volume for the OS that will also house the VHD files for your virtual machines. You're dealing with a single disk array at the hardware layer and creating more than one volume at the OS level doesn't accomplish anything other than making this needlessly complex.

Comment: Skip diskpart, use powershell commandlets.

Comment: I'd suggest you to add the additional 2x120GB SSD for OS partition and use entire RAID-10 SSD's for Hyper-V. And aslo, try using a powershell "Volume Manager" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/san/2012/07/03/managing-storage-with-windows-powershell-on-windows-server-2012/